# How can I align the text and the image like this?

Tags: python, html, css, django

I am very new to python/css/html programing, so please forgive me for asking such a basic question!

I am trying to align my text and my image like the one Dev Ed has in this tutorial (with the image on the right and the text on the left): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C_JKlr4WKKs&t=624s

But, I have not been able to get it to look like that.

I have tried display: grid and its functions (not quite sure if I was doing it correctly), flex, and float.

Here is my about.html's relevant section:

```
        <div class="intro-content">
            <span class="intro-text">
                <h2>Jinyang Zhang</h2>
                <p>Hello and nice to meet you! My name is Jinyang Zhang
                    <br>
                    and currently I am a Kamiak High School student.
                    <br>
                    I am interested in software development and AI
                </p>
            </span>
            <img class="image-resize" src="{% static 'img/me.jpg' %}">
        </div>
```

Here is my styles.css's relevant section:

```
            /*image next to text*/
            .image-resize{
                width: 50vh;
                float: right;
                padding: 150px 100px 0px 0px;
                margin-right: 200px;
            }

            /*introduction text that appears*/
            .intro-text{
                width: 30%;
                padding: 100px 0px 0px 40px;
                /*top right bottom left*/
                transition: 1s all ease-in-out;
                opacity: 0;
                transform: translateY(20px);
                float: left;
            }

            /*animation for it to text to appear like the tutorial*/
            .intro-appear{
                opacity: 1;
                transform: translateY(0px);
            }
```

I would also like it to stay formatted no matter the screen size

Thanks so much for your help1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Flexbox for layout. It makes the CSS very straightforward for aligning things like this. An evergreen resource about flexbox: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/.

I have added a little more HTML too, specifically adding a wrapper around your image so you dont have to worry about the some of the quirks that come up with images as flex children.

Please read the comments for all the reasons nearly every line is there. There's also a red border on the `.content` divs that you can uncomment to see the layout easier.

```js
// Just for demo to add the class after it loads
const text = document.querySelector('.content-text');
setTimeout(function() {
  text.classList.add('intro-appear');
}, 1000);
```

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box } /* bcuz */

/* section of content */
.intro-section {
  padding: 40px 0; /* buffer spacing above and below your content */
  background: #efefef;
}

/* content wrapper */
.intro-content {
  max-width: 1000px; /* Maximum width the content is allowed to be */
  padding: 0 30px; /* content never touches left/right edges */
  display: flex; /* this is a flexbox container now, horizontal by default */
  align-items: center; /* vertical alignment because the image & text are different heights */
  margin: 0 auto; /* center the whole content container horizontally if the screen is wide */
}

/* flex items */
.content {
  flex-grow: 1; /* take up all the space */
  max-width: 50%; /* 50/50 split layout */
  /* border: 1px solid red;  so you can see what's going on, uncomment to view */
}

/* image wrapper */
.content-image {
  display: flex; /* also a flexbox container... */
  align-items: center; /* ...so the img can be easily centered vertically... */
  justify-content: center; /* ...and horizontaly */
}

/* image, this just needs to obey the size of its wrapper now */
.content-image img {
  max-width: 100%; 
  max-height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}

/* introduction text that appears */
.content-text {
  padding: 0 30px;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0;
  
  /*top right bottom left*/
  transition: 1s all ease-in-out;
  transform: translateY(20px);
}


/* animation for it to text to appear like the tutorial */
.intro-appear {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(0px);
}
```

```html
<section class="intro-section">
  <div class="intro-content">
  
    <!-- here is the content, a flex item -->
    <div class="content content-text">
      <h2>Jinyang Zhang</h2>
      <p>Hello and nice to meet you! My name is Jinyang Zhang <br/>
        and currently I am a Kamiak High School student.<br/>
        I am interested in software development and AI</p>
    </div>
    
    <!-- here is the image wrapper, also a flex item -->
    <div class="content content-image">
      <img class="image-resize" src="https://picsum.photos/250/300" />
    </div>
    
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Align an image and a paragraph horizentally and vertically in a section:**

you can create a simple one easily with flex box:

codepen: https://codepen.io/ya3ya6/pen/WBqjBY

Html:

```
     <div class="container">
            <div class="text">
                <h2>Head</h2>
                <p>Paragraph and Paragraph</p>
            </div>
            <img class="image" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1542141372-98a047557466?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=752&q=80">
        </div>
```

Css:

```
.container{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
.container.img{
  width: 50%;
}
.intro-text{
  width: 40%;
}
```

---

also a codepen without changing your structure and animation: https://codepen.io/ya3ya6/pen/mYZmaB